# Trying to get simple excel data to be imported as a social network directed graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

My data has two columns that we'll call A and B. 
The columns proceed as such

**A B**

A1 B1

A2 B2

A3 B3

....

I'm trying to make this into a directed graph where A1 has an outgoing edge to B1 and similarly between A2 and B2 and so on

When I import the excel file, it creates a list like this

```
{{{person A1, person B1}, {person A2, person B2}, .... {person An, person Bn}}}
```

but I can't make a directed graph out of this. So how do I take this very simple two-column format and quickly make it into a directed graph going from persons in column A to persons in column B?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If your list is called `lst`, then perhaps `Graph[Rule @@@ First@lst]`.

Comment: You may also like to add `VertexLabels -> "Name"` as an option to `Graph` to get some simple labeling of your nodes.

Comment: The suggestions here did the trick! Thanks all

Comment: But I'm still confused. what does "Rule @@@ First@lst" mean? I sort of get what each of those expressions means separately, but all together it's confusing

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do computation on the graph, and/or your graph is very large- working with a `SparseArray` and an `AdjacencyGraph` may prove the most beneficial.

Here is a random list which can resemble your data:

```
randomVals = Table[{RandomInteger[10], RandomInteger[20]}, 100];
```

Now we obtain a list of all the values in the list:

```
keys = Union[Join[values[[All, 1]], values[[All, 2]]]];
```

Index all the values in the list:

```
positions = Flatten[MapIndexed[{#1 -> First[#2]} &, keys]];
```

Create a sparse array object and fill it with values:

```
s = SparseArray[
     Flatten[{({#[[1]], #[[2]]} /. positions) -> 1} & /@ randomVals, 1],
     {Max[positions[[All, 2]]], Max[positions[[All, 2]]]}];

AdjacencyGraph[s]
```

[image: adj graph]

p.s. after doing computation on the graph you can always translate the node numbers back to your labels with the reverse of your position vector:

```
(*node values*) /. (Reverse /@ positions)
```